# Node-Cache data won't persist. Clears when page connection reset

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, caching, local-storage

I made this simple example to see how to use the node-cache module. But if I disconnect from node and reconnect the cache gets cleared. Is there a way to make sure the data persists until I clear it? My code is below, thanks for your help.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 3000

const NodeCache = require( "node-cache" );
const myCache = new NodeCache();

app.listen(port, (err :boolean)=> {
if (err){
    return console.log(err);
}
return console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
})

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.originalUrl);
    res.send('I am trying');
})

app.get('/add/:input/:value', (req,res)=>{
    let i = req.params.input;
    let v = req.params.value;
    const success = myCache.set(i, v);
    console.log(success);
    res.send(`key: ${i} value: ${v}`);
})

app.get('/loop', (req,res)=>{
    let mykeys = myCache.keys();

    res.send(mykeys);
})
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by disconnect and reconnect? Restart aplication or reload browser?

Comment: I mean like to "Start the connection" I type "node index.js" and it begins listening on port 5000, and when I hit ctrl C and end that connection, then reconnect (type node index.js again), the data is gone. Does that help? If not I can try explaining a bit better

Comment: Yes it helps a lot. So basically you just restart the app. The node-cache module keeps the data in RAM and does not write it to a file so when you stop the app(hit ctrl+c) the data is gone. You could write the data to a json file yourself just before the app stops or you could use a DB like Redis which is key/value type of DB.